# Warning in arxiv compilation: LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, warnings, auxiliary-files, arxiv

I am trying to upload pdfLaTex of a document on https://arxiv.org/. After compiling, I notice the following.

> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get
> cross-references right.

Everything in my code is fine except for this type of warning. I know the following fact from this [website](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Epjh503/LaTeX/ref.html):

*The first time one runs LaTeX, it goes through making a note of all the labels and all the references and puts this information into the aux file, and then you need to run LaTeX again, without changing the source tex file, in order for LaTeX to get the information from the aux file and sort out which references are which.*

But the arxiv compiler runs a code only once. It means every time I run a code; it will show the same warning.

> **Question:** Is there a way to resolve this?

Like re-compiling the same code twice.

A sample code that I have run on arxiv to get the same warning:

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Sample File}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\RequirePackage[bookmarks, bookmarksopen=true, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, pdfpagelayout=SinglePage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={red!50!black},
    urlcolor={red!80!black}
}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{theorem}
Statement of the theorem. \label{Theorem1}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Here is the proof of \Cref{Theorem1}. See \cite{book}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Statement of the theorem. \label{theorem2}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Here is the proof of \hyperref[theorem2]{Theorem 2}.
\end{proof}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}


\end{document}
```

---

```
Highlighted AutoTeX Log:

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2020 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <main.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: <bibliography.bib> is of type 'BiBTeX'.
[verbose]: <main.bbl> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4345876/ && latex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file main.aux.
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `Theorem1' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `book' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `theorem2' on page 1 undefined on input line 41.


(./main.bbl) [1] (./main.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

)
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 4112 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4345876/ && latex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def) (./main.aux)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./main.out) (./main.out) (./main.bbl) [1] (./main.aux) )
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 5060 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1654679218 >= 1654679217)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1654679218 >= 1654679217)
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.dvi'
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4345876/ && dvips -R2 -z 'main.dvi' -o )" 2>&1
[verbose]: dvi(h)ps said ...
This is dvips(k) 2020.1 Copyright 2020 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2022.06.08:0906' -> main.ps
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texc.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/hps.pro>.
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti8.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb>[1]
<./head.tmp><./body.tmp>
.
[verbose]: Backing up 'main.ps'. Going to change %%Title line.
[verbose]: %%Title: line found and changed.
[verbose]: Title change completed.
[verbose]: Backing up 'main.ps'. Going to add a name/date stamp to it.
[verbose]: OK, inserting the stamp
[verbose]: Stamping completed.
[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: Processing DVI
[verbose]: Gzipping and moving main.dvi
[verbose]: Gzipping ...4345876/main.dvi
[verbose]: Processing postscript
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for bibliography.bib
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.bbl
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.dvi
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.dvi.gz
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.ps
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.tex
[verbose]: Gzipping ...4345876/main.ps
[verbose]: Moving .../4345876/main.ps.gz => .../4345876/tex_cache/4345876.ps.gz

[verbose]: Moving .../4345876/main.dvi.gz => .../4345876/tex_cache/4345876.dvi.gz

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Comment: I can't believe that arxiv runs only once. Are you sure that your references really resolve? Did you try locally and how many compilations do you need there?

Comment: I have run the same code on Overleaf without any error like this.

Comment: I added a sample code with the same warning.

Comment: well the log says they compile for a second time and then without warning. So where is your problem?

Comment: For the original file: This warning comes after the second running, and there is no warning after the third running.  Do you mean this is okay?

Comment: as long as the last run doesn't complain it should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: This is a class of warning that can always be ignored in the first run.

arXiv processes a minimum of twice (if the first pass is successful), and maximally 4 times. This warning will always appear in the first tex pass, if you are using any intra-document `\ref`-type commands and for all `\cite`-type commands if you don't also provide an alt-tex in brackets. If you read through the second pass, you'll notice that this didn't recur, as the citations and refs are now resolved in the `.aux` file generated by the system.

The reason for this: even if you upload a `.aux` file as part of the package, it will be ignored (and removed) by autotex and the cross-references/citations will not be linked in the first pass because the `.aux` file hasn't been populated.